# Error while accessing Sharepoint web service from a Java application

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I currently have a MOSS 2010 installation with the following web applications and sites

Web applications:

1. Sharepoint:80
2. Sharepoint Central Administration
3. Sharepoint_Web_Application:12345 - Another web application that runs on port 12345.

Sites:

1. http://server.mydomain.com
2. http://server.mydomain.com/sites/site1
3. http://server.mydomain.com:65532/        -- This is the default administration site
4. http://server.mydomain.com:12345/sites/site2.

Authentication modes enabled:

1. NTLM
2. Basic
3. Kerberos

I am now trying to access this sharepoint installation using a web services that is deployed globally as a sharepoint solution via a Java client and using the NTLM authentication scheme.

I am able to sucessfully consume the web service when I access it using this URL:

```
http://server.domain.com/_vti_bin/Service.asmx
http://server.domain.com:65432/_vti_bin/Service.asmx
```

However, I get an Axis SOAP fault when I try to access the web service over this URL:

```
http://server.domain.com:12345/_vti_bin/Service.asmx
```

This is really confusing, since I have deployed this web service as a global solution on Sharepoint. Is there any specific setting I need to do within the Sharepoint web application running on 12345 to ensure that the web services are accessible?

Comment: You said that on your server you have "NTLM" "Basic" and "Kerberos" authentication enabled. Authentication is configured per web application. Maybe on your http://server.domain.com:12345 you haven't configured authentication properly?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Thank you for the insight - I will verify the same.

Comment: Are you settings credentials on the client before connection, can you post some of your client code here?